# 3D FlipBook plugin with jQuery in laravel project

Tags: jquery, laravel, pdf, plugins

The case here is that I want to load this 3d flipbook plugin in my laravel project. I downloaded the files and place them in public/js, after that I included the files in master.blade.php . This is how its explained in the plugin here https://3dflipbook.net/getting-started

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/flipbook/js/html2canvas.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/flipbook/js/three.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/flipbook/js/pdf.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/flipbook/js/3dflipbook.min.js') }}"></script>
```

in my blade where the pdf should appear i called it as it's explaind in the plugin like that:

```
<div class="sample-container flip-book-container" src="{{asset('js/flipbook/books/pdf/TheThreeMusketeers.pdf')}}">
    </div>
```

So i see in my page that the plugin take some actions like iframe is appearing ( you can see here https://prnt.sc/180y5kv ) but nothing is showing in my page, the pdf is not visible. And also there is some errors that appear, here you can see https://prnt.sc/180ydfi . I will be very thankful for some help or direction.

Comment: Hello, seems like you're missing the ``media`` directory, can you share your ``public`` folder structure?

Comment: I didn't have that media directory, but now I tried to create it and put there those files from the errors and it worked. Thanks for the direction you gave me :))

Comment: Glad you figured out. This question should be closed now.

Answer (score 0):

Load Chrome this way

To run locally in Chrome you need to start Google Chrome with local file access

1. Close all instances of Chrome
2. Click Start
3. Type in "run" (without quotes) and hit enter
4. Copy paste this line and hit enter:

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```